# rearrange python pandas dataframe

Tags: python, dataframe, pandas

I have a pandas dataframe like following

```
   mp  me        rt                                                         
0  0   1   1.987366                                                         
1  1   1   1.769593                                                         
2  2   1   1.416274                                                         
3  3   1   1.650428                                                         
4  4   1   1.882780                                                         
5  0   2   1.955086                                                         
6  1   2   1.729387                                                         
7  2   2   1.490797                                                         
8  3   2   1.546333                                                         
9  4   2   1.933006
```

I'd like to generate a new dataframe as folloing

```
   mp    me=1       me=2                                                    
0  0   1.987366    1.955086                                                 
1  1   1.769593    1.729387                                                 
2  2   1.416274    1.490797                                                 
3  3   1.650428    1.546333                                                 
4  4   1.882780    1.933006
```

I tried to use a for loop but unsuccessful.

```
for j in range(1,3):
    f[str(j)] = pd.DataFrame(a[a['me']==j]['rt'])
```

Any idea how to do it and effectively?

Thanks.
Dan

Answer (score 6, accepted):

```
In [6]: df.pivot_table(values='rt', rows='mp', cols='me', aggfunc=sum)
Out[6]: 
me         1         2
mp                    
0   1.987366  1.955086
1   1.769593  1.729387
2   1.416274  1.490797
3   1.650428  1.546333
4   1.882780  1.933006
```